# Black screen on xperia U

Tags: android, sony, sony-xperia

I'm developing an app for android.

For some reason a lot of sony xperia users complain that the app launches, 
but the screen is black. No crash , They don't see the content at all .

Reports came from `Xperia U (ST25i).`

I don't get this error on any other device and we have more then `1M` installs.

(I saw the `DialogFragment` issue here, but I'm not using this)

Answer (score 0):

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
    ....
</application>
```

this is due to hardware acceleration enabled. Disabling this will resolve black screen problem.

Comment: Of course this will not go without affecting other functionality -> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: That's what I thought. Disabling hw accel is bad for our app. Is there any documentation of this issue specifically on this xperia model?